# Update DataGrid "Total Quantity" Cell through data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am attempting to have a data grid automatically re-tabulate a "cumulative" count column when the columns that make up that cumulative quantity are changed.

When I change the values in the columns, the TotalQuantity value never updates in the data grid column. I placed an identical data grid in the same view to make sure the data binding was working - and it was. If I made a change in the top data grid, it would be reflected in the lower.

My model:

```
public class HardwareEditorModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int ModelQuantity { get; set; }
    public int ManualQuantity { get; set; }
    public int AutoExtra { get; set; }
    public int TotalQuantity
    {
        get { return ModelQuantity + ManualQuantity + AutoExtra; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class HardwareEditorViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<HardwareEditorModel> _hardwareEditorModels;
    public ObservableCollection<HardwareEditorModel> HardwareEditorModels
    {
        get => _hardwareEditorModels;
        set => SetProperty(ref _hardwareEditorModels, value);
    }

    public HardwareEditorViewModel()
    {
        HardwareEditorModels = new ObservableCollection<HardwareEditorModel>
        {
            new HardwareEditorModel { Description = "NUT", Type = 1, ModelQuantity = 10, ManualQuantity = 0, AutoExtra = 5 },
            new HardwareEditorModel { Description = "BOLT", Type = 0, ModelQuantity = 100, ManualQuantity = 10, AutoExtra = 5 }
        };
    }
}
```

And View:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding HardwareEditorModels, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="200">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model Quantity" Binding="{Binding ModelQuantity}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manual Quantity" Binding="{Binding ManualQuantity}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Auto Extra" Binding="{Binding AutoExtra}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Binding="{Binding TotalQuantity, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let `HardwareEditorModel` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` also, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the computed `TotalQuantity` when one of the underlying properties used to compute it changes (`ModelQuantity`, `ManualQuantity` or `AutoExtra`).

For example like this, making some assumptions about your `ObservableObject` class:

```
public class HardwareEditorModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int _modelQuantity;        
    public int ModelQuantity 
    { 
        get => _modelQuantity;
        set 
        {
            if (!SetProperty(ref _modelQuantity, value)) return;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TotalQuantity));
        }
    }
    // ....
}
```